# Unable to open Code-insiders undefined symbol SHA256

Tags: visual-studio-code, undefined-symbol

I am currently unable to open code-insiders (latest build) The interface loads and then immediately closes, however there are `code-insider` processes left behind still running in back ground that I have to kill directly. 
The error in the log is: 
`/usr/share/code-insiders/code-insiders --unity-launch --enable-crashpad: symbol lookup error: /usr/share/code-insiders/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-encrypt/build/Release/vscode-encrypt-native.node: undefined symbol: SHA256_Init`
 I have seen similar posts that point to the libcrypt and libssh libraries and I have tried re-installing both with no change. I have also purged code and reinstalled the latest build. This still occurs if I try and launch with extensions disabled. 
Any suggestions on where to search next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA256_Init crash problem is due to the vscode-encrypt-native ELF is not linked against lcrypto so the symbols cannot be resolved properly.

You can do a quick fix:

```sh
$ find /usr/lib/ -type f -name "libcrypto.so.*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1

$ sudo apt instal patchelf

$ sudo patchelf --add-needed libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/share/code-insiders/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-encrypt/build/Release/vscode-encrypt-native.node
```

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142656#issuecomment-1034173634